# How can I parse stdclass objects from Amazon Product Advertising API?

Tags: php, parsing, stdclass, amazon-product-api

How would I parse the following to get the `description`, `title` , item number etc...of a product retrieved from Amazon's [Product Advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html)?

I've used the following but it's not consistent.

```
$response  = $client->responseGroup('Small,Images')->category('Books')->search($search);

foreach ($response->Items->Request->Item as $message) {
    echo $message->Description;

}
```

Output below: also found on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/wKPPVyTc). The code below is the output. I want to select the title, description and url data from the object and nothing else preferably in array format.

Any  ideas?

```
        object(stdClass)#6 (2) {
  ["OperationRequest"]=>
  object(stdClass)#7 (4) {
    ["HTTPHeaders"]=>
    object(stdClass)#8 (1) {
      ["Header"]=>
      object(stdClass)#9 (2) {
        ["Name"]=>
        string(9) "UserAgent"
        ["Value"]=>
        string(26) "PHP-SOAP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.18"
      }
    }
    ["RequestId"]=>
    string(36) "cbcaa978-487c-4d83-8986-6a641b7d9c00"
    ["Arguments"]=>
    object(stdClass)#10 (1) {
      ["Argument"]=>
      object(stdClass)#11 (2) {
        ["Name"]=>
        string(7) "Service"
        ["Value"]=>
        string(19) "AWSECommerceService"
      }
    }
    ["RequestProcessingTime"]=>
    float(0.081366)
  }
  ["Items"]=>
  object(stdClass)#12 (5) {
    ["Request"]=>
    object(stdClass)#13 (2) {
      ["IsValid"]=>
      string(4) "True"
      ["ItemSearchRequest"]=>
      object(stdClass)#14 (3) {
        ["Keywords"]=>
        string(9) "airplanes"
        ["ResponseGroup"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          string(5) "Small"
          [1]=>
          string(6) "Images"
        }
        ["SearchIndex"]=>
        string(5) "Books"
      }
    }
    ["TotalResults"]=>
    int(21343)
    ["TotalPages"]=>
    int(2135)
    ["MoreSearchResultsUrl"]=>
    string(237) "http://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html?camp=2025&creative=386001&location=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fgp%2Fsearch%3Fkeywords%3Dairplanes%26url%3Dsearch-alias%253Dstripbooks&linkCode=sp1&tag=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxbet-20&SubscriptionId=AKIAII3UF3HPAPY3SMDQ"
    ["Item"]=>
    array(10) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#15 (8) {
        ["ASIN"]=>
        string(10) "0789465213"
        ["DetailPageURL"]=>
        string(205) "http://www.amazon.com/Big-Book-Airplanes-DK-Publishing/dp/0789465213%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAII3UF3HPAPY3SMDQ%26tag%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbet-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3D0789465213"
        ["ItemLinks"]=>
        object(stdClass)#16 (1) {
          ["ItemLink"]=>
          array(7) {
            [0]=>
            object(stdClass)#17 (2) {
              ["Description"]=>
              string(17) "Technical Details"
              ["URL"]=>
              string(215) "http://www.amazon.com/Big-Book-Airplanes-DK-Publishing/dp/tech-data/0789465213%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAII3UF3HPAPY3SMDQ%26tag%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbet-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0789465213"
            }
            [1]=>
            object(stdClass)#18 (2) {
              ["Description"]=>
              string(20) "Add To Baby Registry"
              ["URL"]=>
              string(211) "http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/baby/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3D0789465213%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAII3UF3HPAPY3SMDQ%26tag%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbet-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0789465213"
            }
            [2]=>
            object(stdClass)#19 (2) {
              ["Description"]=>
              string(23) "Add To Wedding Registry"
              ["URL"]=>
              string(214) "http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wedding/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3D0789465213%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAII3UF3HPAPY3SMDQ%26tag%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbet-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0789465213"
            }
            [3]=>
            object(stdClass)#20 (2) {
              ["Description"]=>
              string(15) "Add To Wishlist"
              ["URL"]=>
              string(215) "http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wishlist/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3D0789465213%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAII3UF3HPAPY3SMDQ%26tag%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbet-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0789465213"
            }
            [4]=>
            object(stdClass)#21 (2) {
              ["Description"]=>
              string(13) "Tell A Friend"
              ["URL"]=>
              string(180) "http://www.amazon.com/gp/pdp/taf/0789465213%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAII3UF3HPAPY3SMDQ%26tag%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbet-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0789465213"
            }
            [5]=>
            object(stdClass)#22 (2) {
              ["Description"]=>
              string(20) "All Customer Reviews"
              ["URL"]=>
              string(184) "http://www.amazon.com/review/product/0789465213%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAII3UF3HPAPY3SMDQ%26tag%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbet-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0789465213"
            }
            [6]=>
            object(stdClass)#23 (2) {
              ["Description"]=>
              string(10) "All Offers"
              ["URL"]=>
              string(186) "http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/0789465213%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAII3UF3HPAPY3SMDQ%26tag%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbet-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0789465213"
            }
          }
        }
        ["SmallImage"]=>
        object(stdClass)#24 (3) {
          ["URL"]=>
          string(60) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51G392LNnWL._SL75_.jpg"
          ["Height"]=>
          object(stdClass)#25 (2) {
            ["_"]=>
            string(2) "75"
            ["Units"]=>
            string(6) "pixels"
          }
          ["Width"]=>
          object(stdClass)#26 (2) {
            ["_"]=>
            string(2) "56"
            ["Units"]=>
            string(6) "pixels"
          }
        }
        ["MediumImage"]=>
        object(stdClass)#27 (3) {
          ["URL"]=>
          string(61) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51G392LNnWL._SL160_.jpg"
          ["Height"]=>
          object(stdClass)#28 (2) {
            ["_"]=>
            string(3) "160"
            ["Units"]=>
            string(6) "pixels"
          }
          ["Width"]=>
          object(stdClass)#29 (2) {
            ["_"]=>
            string(3) "120"
            ["Units"]=>
            string(6) "pixels"
          }
        }
        ["LargeImage"]=>
        object(stdClass)#30 (3) {
          ["URL"]=>
          string(53) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51G392LNnWL.jpg"
          ["Height"]=>
          object(stdClass)#31 (2) {
            ["_"]=>
            string(3) "500"
            ["Units"]=>
            string(6) "pixels"
          }
          ["Width"]=>
          object(stdClass)#32 (2) {
            ["_"]=>
            string(3) "376"
            ["Units"]=>
            string(6) "pixels"
          }
        }
        ["ImageSets"]=>
        object(stdClass)#33 (1) {
          ["ImageSet"]=>
          object(stdClass)#34 (7) {
            ["SwatchImage"]=>
            object(stdClass)#35 (3) {
              ["URL"]=>
              string(60) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51G392LNnWL._SL30_.jpg"
              ["Height"]=>
              object(stdClass)#36 (2) {
                ["_"]=>
                string(2) "30"
                ["Units"]=>
                string(6) "pixels"
              }
              ["Width"]=>
              object(stdClass)#37 (2) {
                ["_"]=>
                string(2) "23"
                ["Units"]=>
                string(6) "pixels"
              }
            }
            ["SmallImage"]=>
            object(stdClass)#38 (3) {
              ["URL"]=>
              string(60) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51G392LNnWL._SL75_.jpg"
              ["Height"]=>
              object(stdClass)#39 (2) {
                ["_"]=>
                string(2) "75"
                ["Units"]=>
                string(6) "pixels"
              }
              ["Width"]=>
              object(stdClass)#40 (2) {
                ["_"]=>
                string(2) "56"
                ["Units"]=>
                string(6) "pixels"
              }
            }
            ["ThumbnailImage"]=>
            object(stdClass)#41 (3) {
              ["URL"]=>
              string(60) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51G392LNnWL._SL75_.jpg"
              ["Height"]=>
              object(stdClass)#42 (2) {
                ["_"]=>
                string(2) "75"
                ["Units"]=>
                string(6) "pixels"
              }
              ["Width"]=>
              object(stdClass)#43 (2) {
                ["_"]=>
                string(2) "56"
                ["Units"]=>
                string(6) "pixels"
              }
            }
            ["TinyImage"]=>
            object(stdClass)#44 (3) {
              ["URL"]=>
              string(61) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51G392LNnWL._SL110_.jpg"
              ["Height"]=>
              object(stdClass)#45 (2) {
                ["_"]=>
                string(3) "110"
                ["Units"]=>
                string(6) "pixels"
              }
              ["Width"]=>
              object(stdClass)#46 (2) {
                ["_"]=>
                string(2) "83"
                ["Units"]=>
                string(6) "pixels"
              }
            }
            ["MediumImage"]=>
            object(stdClass)#47 (3) {
              ["URL"]=>
              string(61) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51G392LNnWL._SL160_.jpg"
              ["Height"]=>
              object(stdClass)#48 (2) {
                ["_"]=>
                string(3) "160"
                ["Units"]=>
                string(6) "pixels"
              }
              ["Width"]=>
              object(stdClass)#49 (2) {
                ["_"]=>
                string(3) "120"
                ["Units"]=>
                string(6) "pixels"
              }
            }
            ["LargeImage"]=>
            object(stdClass)#50 (3) {
              ["URL"]=>
              string(53) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51G392LNnWL.jpg"
              ["Height"]=>
              object(stdClass)#51 (2) {
                ["_"]=>
                string(3) "500"
                ["Units"]=>
                string(6) "pixels"
              }
              ["Width"]=>
              object(stdClass)#52 (2) {
                ["_"]=>
                string(3) "376"
                ["Units"]=>
                string(6) "pixels"
              }
            }
            ["Category"]=>
            string(7) "primary"
          }
        }
        ["ItemAttributes"]=>
        object(stdClass)#53 (4) {
          ["Author"]=>
          string(13) "DK Publishing"
          ["Manufacturer"]=>
          string(11) "DK CHILDREN"
          ["ProductGroup"]=>
          string(4) "Book"
          ["Title"]=>
          string(21) "Big Book of Airplanes"
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#54 (8) {
        ["ASIN"]=>
        string(10) "0753459159"
        ["DetailPageURL"]=>
        string(211) "http://www.amazon.com/Amazing-Airplanes-Machines-Tony-Mitton/dp/0753459159%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAII3UF3HPAPY3SMDQ%26tag%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbet-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3D0753459159"
        ["ItemLinks"]=>
        object(stdClass)#55 (1) {
          ["ItemLink"]=>
          array(7) {
            [0]=>
            object(stdClass)#56 (2) {
              ["Description"]=>
              string(17) "Technical Details"
              ["URL"]=>
              string(221) "http://www.amazon.com/Amazing-Airplanes-Machines-Tony-Mitton/dp/tech-data/0753459159%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAII3UF3HPAPY3SMDQ%26tag%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbet-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0753459159"
            }
            [1]=>
            object(stdClass)#57 (2) {
              ["Description"]=>
              string(20) "Add To Baby Registry"
              ["URL"]=>
              string(211) "http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/baby/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3D0753459159%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAII3UF3HPAPY3SMDQ%26tag%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbet-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0753459159"
            }
            [2]=>
            object(stdClass)#58 (2) {
              ["Description"]=>
              string(23) "Add To Wedding Registry"
              ["URL"]=>
              string(214) "http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wedding/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3D0753459159%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAII3UF3HPAPY3SMDQ%26tag%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbet-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0753459159"
            }
            [3]=>
            object(stdClass)#59 (2) {
              ["Description"]=>
              string(15) "Add To Wishlist"
              ["URL"]=>
              string(215) "http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wishlist/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3D0753459159%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAII3UF3HPAPY3SMDQ%26tag%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbet-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0753459159"
            }
            [4]=>
            object(stdClass)#60 (2) {
              ["Description"]=>
              string(13) "Tell A Friend"
              ["URL"]=>
              string(180) "http://www.amazon.com/gp/pdp/taf/0753459159%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAII3UF3HPAPY3SMDQ%26tag%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbet-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0753459159"
            }
            [5]=>
            object(stdClass)#61 (2) {
              ["Description"]=>
              string(20) "All Customer Reviews"
              ["URL"]=>
              string(184) "http://www.amazon.com/review/product/0753459159%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAII3UF3HPAPY3SMDQ%26tag%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbet-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0753459159"
            }
            [6]=>
            object(stdClass)#62 (2) {
              ["Description"]=>
              string(10) "All Offers"
              ["URL"]=>
              string(186) "http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/0753459159%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAII3UF3HPAPY3SMDQ%26tag%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbet-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0753459159"
            }
          }
        }
        ["SmallImage"]=>
        object(stdClass)#63 (3) {
          ["URL"]=>
          string(60) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51VcEPd9jqL._SL75_.jpg"
          ["Height"]=>
          object(stdClass)#64 (2) {
            ["_"]=>
            string(2) "75"
            ["Units"]=>
            string(6) "pixels"
          }
          ["Width"]=>
          object(stdClass)#65 (2) {
            ["_"]=>
            string(2) "74"
            ["Units"]=>
            string(6) "pixels"
          }
        }
        ["MediumImage"]=>
        object(stdClass)#66 (3) {
          ["URL"]=>
          string(61) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51VcEPd9jqL._SL160_.jpg"
          ["Height"]=>
          object(stdClass)#67 (2) {
            ["_"]=>
            string(3) "160"
            ["Units"]=>
            string(6) "pixels"
          }
          ["Width"]=>
          object(stdClass)#68 (2) {
            ["_"]=>
            string(3) "157"
            ["Units"]=>
            string(6) "pixels"
          }
        }
        ["LargeImage"]=>
        object(stdClass)#69 (3) {
          ["URL"]=>
          string(53) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51VcEPd9jqL.jpg"
          ["Height"]=>
          object(stdClass)#70 (2) {
            ["_"]=>
            string(3) "500"
            ["Units"]=>
            string(6) "pixels"
          }
          ["Width"]=>
          object(stdClass)#71 (2) {
            ["_"]=>
            string(3) "491"
            ["Units"]=>
            string(6) "pixels"
          }
        }
        ["ImageSets"]=>
        object(stdClass)#72 (1) {
          ["ImageSet"]=>
          object(stdClass)#73 (7) {
            ["SwatchImage"]=>
            object(stdClass)#74 (3) {
              ["URL"]=>
              string(60) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51VcEPd9jqL._SL30_.jpg"
              ["Height"]=>
              object(stdClass)#75 (2) {
                ["_"]=>
                string(2) "30"
                ["Units"]=>
                string(6) "pixels"
              }
              ["Width"]=>
              object(stdClass)#76 (2) {
                ["_"]=>
                string(2) "29"
                ["Units"]=>
                string(6) "pixels"
              }
            }
            ["SmallImage"]=>
            object(stdClass)#77 (3) {
              ["URL"]=>
              string(60) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51VcEPd9jqL._SL75_.jpg"
              ["Height"]=>
              object(stdClass)#78 (2) {
                ["_"]=>
                string(2) "75"
                ["Units"]=>
                string(6) "pixels"
              }
              ["Width"]=>
              object(stdClass)#79 (2) {
                ["_"]=>
                string(2) "74"
                ["Units"]=>
                string(6) "pixels"
              }
            }
            ["ThumbnailImage"]=>
            object(stdClass)#80 (3) {
              ["URL"]=>
              string(60) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51VcEPd9jqL._SL75_.jpg"
              ["Height"]=>
              object(stdClass)#81 (2) {
                ["_"]=>
                string(2) "75"
                ["Units"]=>
                string(6) "pixels"
              }
              ["Width"]=>
              object(stdClass)#82 (2) {
                ["_"]=>
                string(2) "74"
                ["Units"]=>
                string(6) "pixels"
              }
            }
            ["TinyImage"]=>
            object(stdClass)#83 (3) {
              ["URL"]=>
              string(61) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51VcEPd9jqL._SL110_.jpg"
              ["Height"]=>
              object(stdClass)#84 (2) {
                ["_"]=>
                string(3) "110"
                ["Units"]=>
                string(6) "pixels"
              }
              ["Width"]=>
              object(stdClass)#85 (2) {
                ["_"]=>
                string(3) "108"
                ["Units"]=>
                string(6) "pixels"
              }
            }
            ["MediumImage"]=>
            object(stdClass)#86 (3) {
              ["URL"]=>
              string(61) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51VcEPd9jqL._SL160_.jpg"
              ["Height"]=>
              object(stdClass)#87 (2) {
                ["_"]=>
                string(3) "160"
                ["Units"]=>
                string(6) "pixels"
              }
              ["Width"]=>
              object(stdClass)#88 (2) {
                ["_"]=>
                string(3) "157"
                ["Units"]=>
                string(6) "pixels"
              }
            }
            ["LargeImage"]=>
            object(stdClass)#89 (3) {
              ["URL"]=>
              string(53) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51VcEPd9jqL.jpg"
              ["Height"]=>
              object(stdClass)#90 (2) {
                ["_"]=>
                string(3) "500"
                ["Units"]=>
                string(6) "pixels"
              }
              ["Width"]=>
              object(stdClass)#91 (2) {
                ["_"]=>
                string(3) "491"
                ["Units"]=>
                string(6) "pixels"
              }
            }
            ["Category"]=>
            string(7) "primary"
          }
        }
        ["ItemAttributes"]=>
        object(stdClass)#92 (4) {
          ["Author"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(11) "Tony Mitton"
            [1]=>
            string(10) "Ant Parker"
          }
          ["Manufacturer"]=>
          string(10) "Kingfisher"
          ["ProductGroup"]=>
          string(4) "Book"
          ["Title"]=>
          string(36) "Amazing Airplanes (Amazing Machines)"
        }
      }
      [2]=>
      object(stdClass)#93 (8) {
        ["ASIN"]=>
        string(10) "0061143812"
        ["DetailPageURL"]=>
        string(214) "http://www.amazon.com/In-Cockpit-Inside-History-Making-Aircraft/dp/0061143812%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAII3UF3HPAPY3SMDQ%26tag%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbet-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3D0061143812"
        ["ItemLinks"]=>
        object(stdClass)#94 (1) {
          ["ItemLink"]=>
          array(7) {
            [0]=>
            object(stdClass)#95 (2) {
              ["Description"]=>
              string(17) "Technical Details"
              ["URL"]=>
              string(224) "http://www.amazon.com/In-Cockpit-Inside-History-Making-Aircraft/dp/tech-data/0061143812%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAII3UF3HPAPY3SMDQ%26tag%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbet-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0061143812"
            }
            [1]=>
            object(stdClass)#96 (2) {
              ["Description"]=>
              string(20) "Add To Baby Registry"
              ["URL"]=>
              string(211) "http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/baby/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3D0061143812%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAII3UF3HPAPY3SMDQ%26tag%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbet-20%26linkCode%3Dsp1%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0061143812"


etc....
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all you can print response array to view in array format then get element which you want, example below :)

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($response); 
echo '</pre>';

foreach($response['Items']['Item'] as $item)
{

    echo 'asin :'.$item[ASIN].'<br>';
    echo 'Title :'.$item[ItemAttributes][Title].'<br>';
    echo '<image src="'.$item[MediumImage][URL].'">';


}
```

Comment: You will receive an error. Cannot use object of type stdClass as array